# Kruskal-Wallis versus Friedman - Paired data, but not repeated measures/blocks?

Tags: nonparametric, paired-data, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

I'm trying to compare the difference in behaviour of an animal with no enrichment to the same animal with two (or more) types of enrichment.  (Total active behaviours before/total active behaviours with enrichment A/Total active behaviours with enrichment B etc)
As it is the same animal each time, the results of each trial are not completely independent so I can't use a Kruskal-Wallis (?)

The 'flow charts' I can find all lead me to use a Friedman test in this case.  However, I do not have any 'blocks' as it wasn't a repeated measures design.  How can I find if there is an impact of enrichment on active behaviours.

(10 x 1 hour observations recording total 'active behaviours' observed every 15 seconds, then averaged across the 10 sample observations.  Repeated for each type of enrichment.  Results do not show a normal distribution and so I can't use an ANOVA.)

Comment: So you have only one animal in your sample? And you tried different treatments on this one animal? If not, how many animals do you have?

Comment: If you have enough animals this may be a place for an ordinal regression model (e.g. proportional odds model) with random effects for animals.

Comment: I see that @user2974951 comment was never addressed, but I have a similar issue and am wondering what the answer might be if the answer is yes, only one animal.

Comment: @selene Well, there is no statistics with only 1 subject/object/participant/animal, at most what you can say is what the effect was like for this specific animal. In any case, I would try a linear mixed model, where the animal is the random effect (even though there is only 1 such effect).

Comment: @user2974951 thanks. that is what I am trying to figure out...did a group of animals change a metric of their behavior in response to a treatment, compared to what their behavior was before the treatment. 

I multiple groups of animals that were 'treated' but I'm working with wild populations so overall sample size is pretty small and I can't control for things like group size or baseline behavior because it is often hugely different. 

I will look into linear mixed models! Thanks